# Strange Error with Vectors in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vector, directx

Every time I compile the code for a RTS Project I am working on, I get this error:

```
error C2664: 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc> std::vector<_Ty>::erase(std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc>)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'MAPTILE *' to 'std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc>'
```

The code area that I have for this method is this:

```
MAPTILE *startTile = GetTile(start);
    MAPTILE *goalTile = GetTile(goal);
```

...

```
    std::vector<MAPTILE*> open;             //Create Our Open list
    startTile->g = 0;                       //Init our starting point (SP)
    startTile->f = H(start, goal);
    startTile->open = true;
    open.push_back(startTile);              //Add SP to the Open list

    bool found = false;                  // Search as long as a path hasnt been found,
    while(!found && !open.empty())       // or there is no more tiles to search
    {                                               
        MAPTILE * best = open[0];        // Find the best tile (i.e. the lowest F value)
        int bestPlace = 0;
        for(int i=1;i<open.size();i++)
            if(open[i]->f < best->f)
            {
                best = open[i];
                bestPlace = i;
            }

        if(best == NULL)break;          //No path found

        open[bestPlace]->open = false;
        open.erase(&open[bestPlace]);   // Take the best node out of the Open list
```

I have searched on this website and a few others, but I could not find the correct area.

I am reading "Programming a RTS Game With Direct3D" By Carl Granberg.

All of my code is right because I matched it with the source code, and I got the same error.

I am using Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition.

I have never gotten this error before.

Answer (score 2):

`erase` wants an iterator and you are giving it a pointer to an element within the array.  Use `std::advance` or keep a handle to an iterator.

```
std::vector<MAPTILE*> p = open.begin();
std::advance(p, bestPlace);
open.erase(p);
```

**EDIT** *I forgot that `std::advance` doesn't return anything.  Sorry about that.  I haven't done serious C++ development for about five years.*

I would rewrite your `for` loop to use iterators instead of indexes.

I believe that the following snippet is equivalent to your snippet after replacing the array indexing with iterators.  I had to add the `typedef` to make it more readable.

```
    MAPTILE *startTile = GetTile(0);
    startTile->g = 0;
    startTile->f = H(0, 10);
    startTile->open = true;

    std::vector<MAPTILE*> open;
    open.push_back(startTile);

    typedef std::vector<MAPTILE*>::iterator Iterator;
    bool found = false;
    while (!found && !open.empty()) {
            Iterator best = open.begin();
            for (Iterator iter=best+1, end=open.end();
                 iter!=end; ++iter)
            {
                    if ((*iter)->f < (*best)->f) {
                            best = iter;
                    }
            }
            if (*best == NULL) {
                    break;
            }
            (*best)->open = false;
            open.erase(best);
    }
```

I'm not completely convinced that the `if (*best == NULL)` condition will ever be matched though.  This compiles without error under `clang++` (sorry, no visual studio in my house).  When I run your snippet through `clang++`, I get comparable failures to yours:

```
foo.cpp:85:14: error: calling a private constructor of class
      'std::__1::__wrap_iter<MAPTILE *const *>'
                open.erase(&open[bestPlace]);
                           ^
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/iterator:1381:31: note:
      declared private here
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY __wrap_iter(iterator_type __x) _NOEXCEPT_D...
                              ^
1 error generated.
```

I don't know what else to say, `std::vector<>::erase` takes a `std::vector<>::iterator` parameter and that's all that there is to it.  My guess is that the book was written against a version of VC++ that used pointers for vector iterators though I don't recall one that ever did that.

Comment: That Did not Work... I got the same error, but instead of it saying "MAPTILE", it says "void"

Comment: I will send you anything in the project you want. Just say what you might need. I can send you the MAPTILE definition if you want.

Comment: What everyone needs here is a [mcve]. The shown question fails to meet the requirements for a [mcve] as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help]. This answer is correct based solely on the information given in the question, but since the question fails to be a [mcve], there are obviously other issues with your code, but without a [mcve] nothing further can be done.

Comment: All other code before this example in the book works, just not this particular one.

Comment: @rjhwinner03 *There is nothing wrong with the code, dude* -- Sorry, but there is something wrong with the code.  Are you saying that the compiler is incorrect?

Comment: Here is a list of my technology:

Comment: DirectX 9, Visual C++ 2008, Visual C++ 2010, and/or Visual C++ 6

Comment: The code assumes that vector iterators are implemented as pointers, which is why more than likely the address-of an entry worked in the `erase` call.  That *may* have been the case with Visual 6.0, but no more.  Iterators are iterators, and the correct syntax should have been used from the start.  This answer given to you is the answer that fixes the error in the book.

Comment: It must be visual C++ 7.0, because with Visual C++ 6, it fails because of the "for" loops

Comment: This has gone too far off the track.  Please provide a [mcve], not a description of the code.  Second, this `open.erase(&open[bestPlace]);` is crap code that "worked" in Visual C++ 6.0, but will no longer work for any version of Visual Studio that does not implement vector iterators as mere pointers.  If the author were more careful, the answer provided would have worked for Visual 6.0, 7.0, 2008, 2015, etc.

Comment: Sir, please just help me find an installer for Visual C++ 7

Comment: I already have visual C++ 6, but I have errors with for loops: an essential part of programming.

Comment: If anyone can forward this question to another website, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @rjhwinner03 @PaulMcKenzie is probably correct about VC++ 6 intermixing pointers and iterators.  That would be about the right place in history for the behavior.  Note that VC++ 6 is the first one that implemented `for` loop variable scoping IIRC.  I know that VC++5 was hopelessly broken in that department.

Comment: Could you give me a link to vc++ 7? It would be a combination of the two I have and it is the one used to compile the code.

Comment: The book used visual c++ 7.

Comment: Do you know any modifications for vc++ 6 or vc++ 2008 that would make it seem like I was using vc++ 7? I have vc++ 6 and 2008.

Comment: @rjhwinner03 - unfortunately Visual Studio don't usually feature "compatibility" flags. Most of the time the newer versions are simply more compliant to the standards. Part of learning how to program is learning how to adapt examples to your specific environment. Take this as a learning opportunity. Change the example to work (use iterators) and move forward. When you encounter another problem, ask questions, fix the problem, and continue forward. Good luck!

Comment: Sadly, I have been banned from asking questions. This particular question was the straw that broke the camel's back.

Comment: m_members.erase(m_members.begin());

Comment: Im reading one of paul mckenzi's posts about a new error I am getting. It is here: http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?508403-Assertion-on-Vector-Insertion